# Multiple labels with Jquery autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to implement Autocomplete on my project with Jquery UI, however I would like to have a small modification.

the PHP that is called dynamically is :

```
<?php 
include "../../connections/connect.inc.php";


$return_arr = array();


$search_term = "%".$_GET['term']."%";
$moviesquery = "SELECT * FROM movie where movie_name like :term";
$movieresults = $dbconnection->prepare($artistsquery);
$movieresults->bindValue(":term",$search_term);
$movieresults->execute();

/* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
while ($row = $movieresults->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

$return_arr[] = array('label'=>$row['movie_name'],'value'=>$row['movie_name']); //build an array
//array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

/* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

This is what I have written in my JQuery call :

```
$(function() {
    $("#movie_name").autocomplete({
       source: "sendmovies.php",
       minLength: 3
    })
});
```

The problem is, I want to see more information on each movie in the autocomplete suggestions. Currently the autocomplete works and shows only the movie name. I want it to display the country below the name, and the release year. when the user clicks on it, I want the autocomplete to take only the value of the movie name. And possibly, get the movie ID into a hidden field as well. I am a Jquery noobie so if anyone could help me I would be very glad.

Thank you all.

Comment: You could push down the whole thing (movie name + year, etc.) and let the user search on the whole string

Comment: Thank you, but actually, I want to search only using the name, and the autocomplete should display the movie country and year besides just the name. It is somewhat like we see in facebook, where it says "Apple and then "Organization" in small letters below it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this part:

> And possibly, get the movie ID into a hidden field as well. I am a
>   Jquery noobie so if anyone could help me I would be very glad.

jQuery:

```
$( "#movie_name" ).autocomplete({
    select: function(event, ui){
      if(ui.item.value == ""){
        return false;
      }else{
        //here start your logic (its executed when you select the result
        $('input.hidden').val(ui.item.id);
        $('input[name=any]').val(ui.item.val);
      }
    }
});
```

and you need to add:

```
/* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
while ($row = $movieresults->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

$return_arr[] = array(
    'label'=>$row['movie_name'], 
    'value'=>$row['movie_name'], 'id' => $row['id'], 
    'anyother_ui_name' => $row['value']); //build an array
//array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! Can someone help me with the other half of the question ?:)